# ios 9 iphone 6S Play Haptic feedback or vibrate

Tags: ios9, 3dtouch

After user does force touch, I want to vibrate phone just like default behaviour.

Is it haptic? If so, how shall I do?

Answer (score 16):

Example in Swift (for iPhone 6S)

```swift
import AudioToolbox

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) // Actuate `Peek` feedback (weak boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520) // Actuate `Pop` feedback (strong boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1521) // Actuate `Nope` feedback (series of three weak booms)
```

Just in case - here're examples for [iPhone 7/7+](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/01/29/haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator/).

As for the force touch - you need to detect if it's available first:

```swift
func is3dTouchAvailable(traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> Bool {
    return traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available
}
```

and then in touch events, it will be available as touch.force

```swift
func touchMoved(touch: UITouch, toPoint pos: CGPoint) {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let node = self.atPoint(location)

    //...
    if is3dTouchEnabled {
        bubble.setPressure(pressurePercent: touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce)
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here's my blog with a more detailed example with code samples:
http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/02/01/swift-how-to-use-3d-touch-introduction/

Comment: The 1519-1521 codes don't seem to apply here anymore. Did you happen to bump into issues? @Mikita Manko

Answer (score 13):

Starting with **iOS 10**, there is a new public API for handling haptic feedback: [`UIFeedbackGenerator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator).

```swift
let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
```

It is suggested to call `.prepare()` before using the generator and sending the feedback as there is a slight delay between the two due to the feedback hardware requiring a "wakeup". This could be done in `viewDidLoad()` or something comparable if you are expecting the feedback to be given shortly after.

See this blog for a good explanation of the new API and the available feedbacks:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-generate-haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator

**For iOS 9 and older**, you could use AudioToolBox as outlined in the other posts.

```swift
import AudioToolbox

private let isDevice = TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR == 0

func vibrate() {
    if isDevice {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional haptic classes in iOS 10: [UIImpactFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimpactfeedbackgenerator) and [UISelectionFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiselectionfeedbackgenerator)

Comment: @bendytree Thanks for adding the new subclasses, I don't always have a look at older posts here :)

Answer (score 6):

There are different feedback types. Try each one to figure out what is better for your needs:

```swift
// 1, 2, 3
let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
generator.notificationOccurred(.error)
generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
generator.notificationOccurred(.warning)

// 4
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
generator.impactOccurred()

// 5
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
generator.impactOccurred()

// 6
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
generator.impactOccurred()

// 7
let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
generator.selectionChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are talking about the new Taptic Engine.

From apple.com: *iPhone 6s gives you real-time feedback both onscreen and in the form of subtle taps from the **Taptic Engine**. These responses correspond to how deeply you’re pressing the display, and they let you know what actions you’re performing and what you can expect to happen.*

As I know actually there is no public API for that.
I've only found [this tutorial](http://unifiedsense.com/development/using-taptic-engine-on-ios.html) for implementing the Taptic feedback via private API.

```c
//ATTENTION: This is a private API, if you use this lines of code your app will be rejected

id tapticEngine = [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"_tapticEngine") withObject:nil];
[tapticEngine performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"actuateFeedback:") withObject:@(0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom logic to achieve this:

- Detect a force applied on the screen by a user, by using `force` and `maximumPossibleForce` properties of `UITouch` class.
- Depending upon the force amount, you can vibrate device after particular level.

Example:

```c
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGFloat maximumPossibleForce = touch.maximumPossibleForce;
    CGFloat force = touch.force;
    CGFloat normalizedForce = force/maximumPossibleForce;
    NSLog(@"Normalized force : %f", normalizedForce);

    if (normalizedForce > 0.75)
    {
         NSLog(@"Strong");
        // Vibrate device
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Weak");
    }
}
```

- Also, you can try to set different vibration duration for different force level with custom logic.

Example:

```c
// Vibrate device
NSTimer * vibrationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(vibrateDevice) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


- (void) vibrateDevice
{
    if(duration == 2) // duration is a public variable to count vibration duration
    {
          // Stop the device vibration
          [vibrationTimer invalidate];
          return;
    }

    duration++;
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```